# Отсутствие переводов на странице редактирования информации пользователя

Tags: дефект, локализация, настройки-профиля

Обнаружил что нет переводов на странице редактора информации о пользователе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

судя по вопросам на Мете данная тема не поднималась, либо я плохо искал) Судя по тому что я нашел в traducir.win часть переводов скоро подтянется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[link](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16835)

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[link](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16829)

добавил:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### [link](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=My%20logins)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[link](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16834)

Спасибо [MSDN.WhiteKnight](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/240512/msdn-whiteknight) за добавление переводов

Comment: Переводы просто так не подтянутся. Их нужно ещё предварительно утвердить. Право утверждать есть у [участников](https://ru.traducir.win/users) с ролью Reviewer. И вместо скриншотов с traducir.win лучше приводить ссылки, чтобы как раз было проще проверить/утвердить нужные переводы.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, добавил для всех вроде скринов ссылки, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Утвердил предложенные переводы. Будет доступно в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.8.24.40058

Comment: спасибо)) а стоит вообще такие вопросы публиковать?) я просто вот только сегодня впервые добавил переводы, раньше вас приходилось дергать) или просто вносить а там если что поправят?

Comment: Конечно стоит публиковать. А предложения вариантов перевода можно сразу как ответ на свой вопрос оформить. Будет и мета-репутация-знаки фармиться  заодно :) Ну и чтобы ревьюверы всё это заметили - мета самое подходящее место для этого. Плюс для истории всё это останется.

Comment: я понял, сейчас оформлю) просто я раньше думал что всё что я внесу сразу затащится, не знал что есть ещё и ревьюверы)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил переводы для [Способы входа](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16837) и [Скрыть cообщества](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16834)